# what is the default Storage location in File Object

Tags: java, file, file-upload, jvm, apache-poi

In this code i didn't mention the path for the file hello.xls. But, I am reading the values from hello.txt file but i don't know where it gets stored. Is it stored in the JVM memory or some where else. if so what is the maximum size. I am using unix box.

sample java code:

```
File f = new File(hello.xls);
InputStream f = new FileInputStream(f);
```

If it is store some where in the server, Please suggest, how to handle without storing the files in the server to read the values and write the values in the same excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default storage location in `File` object is a directory obtained by executing the line :

```
System.getProperty("user.dir"); //represents the current directory the user is executing the program, rather than where the program is located.
```

It's the directory from where the java was run -- where you started the JVM.

Comment: How to avoid this?... How to read & write the excel file without storing any of the places in the server. Is there any other alternate approach to overcome this? Please help me on this.

Comment: i mean..with out storing it anywhere how can we read & write in to it...u want it to store on remote location/client location

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadocs, if you don't specify a path in the file constructor, the file is assumed to be in the directory pointed to by the

> "system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the
>   Java virtual machine was invoked."